# Solving this first-order differential equation for neutron abundance using given data

Tags: computational-physics, big-bang, nucleosynthesis

The time rate of change of neutron abundance $X_n$ is given by
$$\frac{dX_n}{dt} = \lambda - (\lambda + \hat\lambda)X_n$$
where $\lambda$ is neutron production rate per proton and $\hat\lambda$ is neutron destruction rate per neutron.
Given the values of $\lambda$ and $\hat\lambda$ at various values of time, I need to calculate $X_n$.

[image]

I have also calculated values of $\lambda 's$ at intermediate times. I have tried using Euler method and RK4 method to solve this equation, but the solutions for $X_n$ diverge to inf values.

[Here](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1966ApJ...146..542P/abstract) is the link to the complete research paper "Primordial Helium Abundance and the Primordial Fireball. II" by P.J.E. Peebles.

Any help or idea on how to solve it will be appreciated : )

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed, as the answer is directly related to the first and second points of *allowed* questions on the [tag info page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info) (specifically, advising on numerical methods tied to a physical problem & scheme limitations). Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on Physicsforums [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/solving-this-first-order-differential-equation-for-neutron-abundance.1051288/), the differential equation is a
[stiff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). So it is bound to diverge using explicit Euler method (and probably RK4) method. The solution is to use some adaptive step size method.